# Managing permissions in a large Laravel project using Exceptions?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

I'm working on a big Laravel project that has 5 user types, around 50 models and the same amount of controllers.

Each user type has their own permissions calculated from a separate table based on different factors, so a simple model policy won't work.

What I have done so far, is to create a policy for each model and do the calculation there:

```
class MyModelPolicy {
    function someActionName(){
        // Check whether user have the permission or not.
        // I only return a simple true/false here, as I might need to 
        // reuse this somewhere else.
        return $resultAsBoolean;
    }
}
```

Now, in the controllers, I'm using a helper function that uses the `Gate` facade and throws a custom exception:

```
function checkUserAccess( $someActionName, $args = [ 'some arguments' ] ){
    $gate = Gate::inspect( $someActionName, $args );
    if( $gate->denied() ) {
        // Throw exception here
        throw new PermissionDeniedException( 'message here' );
    }
}
```

And the controller itself:

```
public function store(){
    // Check permissions
    checkUserAccess('permissions to check');
   // All good, continue
}
```

And for the final part, I have defined a custom exception that extends the base Laravel extension class, and has a `render()` method that decided what to do:

```
class PermissionDeniedException extends Exception {
    public function render(){
        /**
         * Our custom permissionDeniedException has been
         * triggered. Do the right action based on the 
         * current situation. This will always terminate the app.
         */
    }
}
```

Now I know that using exception for flow-control is not a good idea, but since this exception will terminate the app completely, I don't feel too bad about using it. However, the only problem here is that every single method of my controller ( around 350 total ) can now throw an exception. I thought about solving this by setting all methods to private, and then use the `__call()` magic method and only throw an exception from there.

Is there any better solution for this situation? or is this inevitable when the project gets too complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing exceptions is a normal approach for handling flows, that has to terminate and have specific responses. This ties well in with the Exception `Handler.php`.

Your solution is fine, but in general there is syntactic sugar for what you are trying to do. Shown below, if the permission is not there, an `Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException` will be thrown.

```
Gate::authorize('permissions to check', $yourModel);
```

> However, the only problem here is that every single method of my
> controller ( around 350 total ) can now throw an exception

This is a non problem, imagine if you use Model binding, eg. Model injection by URl parameter. From everywhere that is used, it can throw a `ModelNotFoundException`. Those will be handled by the Exception `Handler.php` and in my opinion there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that throwing exception is an expensive operation, but considering the fact that this exception will terminate he application, I guess it would be fine. Btw, I assume it's possible to modify the exception that the gate throws and throw a custom exception instead, is that true?